# Dynamically creating a class of generic type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like this

```
public class ViewModelBase<T> : Notifier
{
    private readonly string _tabHeaderPath;
    private readonly T _view;
    public ViewModelBase(T view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }
    public ViewModelBase(T view, string tabHeaderPath)
    {
        _view = view;
        _tabHeaderPath = tabHeaderPath;
    }
    public T View
    {
        get { return _view; }
    }
    public string TabHeaderPath
    {
        get { return _tabHeaderPath; }

    }
}
```

I want to get an object of this using reflection something like this.

```
object PresenterBase= null;
Assembly assembly =  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
object objView = null;
// Walk through each type in the assembly looking for our class
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsClass == true)
    {
        if (type.FullName.EndsWith("." + "GeneralEnquiryViewModel"))
        {
            // create an instance of the object


            foreach(Type objType2 in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if(objType2.IsClass==true)
                {
                    if (objType2.FullName.EndsWith("." + "GeneralEnquiryView"))
                    {
                        objView = Activator.CreateInstance(objType2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(GeneralEnquiryView), typeof(string) });

             PresenterBase= ctor.Invoke(new object[] { objView, "GeneralEnquiry" });
         }
    }
}
```

I am able to do like this:

```
ViewModelBase<GeneralEnquiryView> objPresenter = GeneralEnquiryViewModel(PresenterBase);
```

But i want to replace GeneralEnquiryView to objview and GeneralEnquiryViewModel to PresenterBase so that i get an instance of objPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383784/c-sharp-reflection-invoke-constructor-of-generic-class

Comment: Hi yuval,i am able to create the obejct of presenterBase but how to convert it to generic class of ViewModelBase.or should i approach another way